# How to append to bson object

Tags: mongodb, go

I have an endpoint where users can filter a mongo collection using query parameters. If I have just one query parameter e.g. `title`, I can do this -

```
filter := bson.M{}

if params.Title != "" {
    filter = bson.M{"title": params.Title}
}
```

However, if I have more than one query parameter, I can't seem to get how to append to the `bson` object.

I tried this -

```
filter := []bson.M{}

if params.Title != "" {
    filter = append(filter, bson.M{"title": params.Title})
}

if params.Description != "" {
    filter = append(filter, bson.M{"description": params.Description})
}
```

but I got this error - `cannot transform type []primitive.M to a BSON Document: WriteArray can only write a Array while positioned on a Element or Value but is positioned on a TopLevel`

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[bson.M{}](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/v1.5.2/bson/bson.go#L45) is underlined `map[string]interface{}` in [go-mongo-driver](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver). So if you need to add more elemnets, you can not append. Just assign that value to map's key as below.

```
    filter := bson.M{}
    
    if params.Title != "" {
        //filter = bson.M{"title": params.Title}
        filter["title"] = params.Title
    }

    if params.Description != "" {
        filter["description"] =  params.Description
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a collection `test` with a document: `{ "_id" : 1, "Title" : "t-1", "Description" : "d-1" }`
And, you can use the following:

```
title := "t-1"
description := ""    // or "d-1"
filter := bson.M{}

if Title != "" {
    filter["Title"] = title
}

if Description != "" {
    filter["Description"] = description
}

//fmt.Println(filter);

var result bson.M

collection := client.Database("test").Collection("test")
err := collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), filter).Decode(&result)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("Found a single document: %+v\n", result)
```